# Use variables supplied to aes_string() in other ggplot functions

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I'm using `aes_string()` in a function to create some graphs. I'm using cowplot for theming and this scales the axes to the maximum values of the data provided, cutting off the top or side of the points at the maximum as in the example below.

I therefore want to add 5% to the max data for the column to add a little space. If I were not writing a function I could do something like

```
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), 
                       limits = c(0, max(y_var) *  1.05))
```

However, I don't know how to do this with `aes_string()`. Can anyone explain how to do this with `aes_string()`?

```
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)

fig_fun <- function(data, var){
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x = "wt", y = var)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), 
                       limits = c(0, NA))
}

data("mtcars")
p <- fig_fun(data = mtcars, var = "mpg")
p
```

[image: current problem]

Comment: Don't send `expand = c(0, 0)` if you want the axis to expand.

Comment: Can you not just use `max(data[, var]) ` to get maximum of all the values for the `y` variable? Then you change this as you want.

Comment: @Roland, well unfortunately I have been imposed with a requirement that the x axis crosses the y at zero, hence `expand = c(0, 0)`

Comment: @niczky12, that works perfectly, do you want to add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the `y` variable from your data inside the `expand_limits` and scale that by 5%:

```
expand_limits(y = c(0, max(data[, var])*1.05))
```

Which makes:

```
fig_fun <- function(data, var){
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x = "wt", y = var)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point() +
    expand_limits(y = c(0,max(data[, var])*1.05))) # picking the var column here
}
```

You will need an additional `+ scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))` to absolutely limit to those numbers.

But as others suggested, if you use the default value for `expand` parameter of `scale_y_continuous` you'd get what you want.
So `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0.1))` would give you 10% extra space from your y axis boundaries on either side. Docs are [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html).

The `expand_limits` method is still useful if you want some more custom solutions.

Comment: ah, well I did `limits = c(0, max(data[, var]) * 1.05)` because of the requirement to pass through zero as described in the above comment. But, thanks, this got me what I needed.

Comment: This is not how the `expand` argument works. The two numbers are multiplicative and additive constants for both ends. So if one would want a 5% increase in scale you'd give `c(0.05, 0)` (which is already the default). @r.bot has the correct solution of setting the `limits` (together with `expand = c(0, 0)`).

Comment: @Axeman you're right. I got mixed up with `expand_limits`. Change the answer accordingly.